# how to tie variables in c++

Tags: c++, variables, assembly, casting

Well my problem is as follows:
I'm trying to translate an x86 assembly source code to c++ source code.

```
Explanation as to what registers are.
    skip this if you know what they are and how they work.    
As you may or may not know, assembly language makes use of "general purpose registers".
    In x86 assembly these registers are, and can be considered as "4 bytes" in length variables ( int var in c++ ), their names are: eax, ebx, ecx and edx.
    Now, these registers are each respectively broken down into ax, bx, cx and dx that represent the 2 bytes less significant value of each register.
    ax, bx, cx and dx are also broken down into ah, bx, ch and dh ( most significant byte ) and al, bl, cl and dl ( less significant byte ).
    So, for example:
    If I set eax:
    EAX = 0xAB12CDEF
    that would automatically change ax, al and ah
    AX would become 0xCDEF
    AH would become 0xCD
    AL would become 0xEF
```

My question is: How do I make that possible in C++ ?

```
int eax, ax, ah, al;
eax = 0xAB12CDEF
```

How can I make, ax, ah and al, change at the same time?
Or is it possible to make them pointers to different portions eax, if so, how?
Thanks!
P.S. Also how could i use  to make another variable be a char ?
How could I make variable new variable "char chAL" point to al which points to eax.
So that when i make a change to chAL, the changes would automatically reverberate to eax, ah and al.

Comment: How portable do you want the resulting code to be? x86 is necessarily little-endian, whereas C++ is not, so the location of the least-significant byte is different on different C++ implementations. Also, what features do you need? If you need to be able to write to `ax` then that's an extra thing to consider. Normally you wouldn't translate x86 to C++ this literally.

Comment: I would like to translate this literally because the code is non linear. As an example I would say that: compare eax with ebx and only 20 instructions after the comparison was made (i.e. flags register set) make the decision as to whether jump or not. Or: move 5 in eax, mess with ax, ah, al, use ax, ah and al for three different unrelated purposes and then finally return eax. The point is that I have to work with 4 different values per register and that complicates things where a small change to al, could mean bad consequences for the other variable if not set correctly at the correct time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to emulate X86 assembly code, then indeed you need to support the behaviour of X86 registers.

Here's a simple implementation using a `union`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

union reg_t {
    uint64_t rx;
    uint32_t ex;
    uint16_t x;
    struct {
        uint8_t l;
        uint8_t h;
    };
};

int main(){
    reg_t a;

    a.rx = 0xdeadbeefcafebabe;

    cout << "rax = " << hex << a.rx << endl;
    cout << "eax = " << hex << a.ex << endl;
    cout << "ax  = " << hex << a.x << endl;
    cout << "al  = " << hex << (uint16_t)a.l << endl;
    cout << "ah  = " << hex << (uint16_t)a.h << endl;

    cout << "ax & 0xFF      = " << hex << (a.x & 0xFF) << endl;
    cout << "(ah << 8) + al = " << hex << (a.h << 8) + a.l << endl;

}
```

output:

```
rax = deadbeefcafebabe
eax = cafebabe
ax  = babe
al  = be
ah  = ba
ax & 0xFF      = be
(ah << 8) + al = babe
```

You'll get the correct result on the right platform (little-endian). You'll have to swap
bytes, and/or add padding for other platforms.

That's the basic, down to earth solution, which will certainly work on many x86 platforms (at least X86/linux/g++ works fine), *but the behaviour this very approach relies on seems undefined in C++*.

Here's another approach using a byte array to store register content:

```
class x86register {

  uint8_t bytes[8]; 

public:

  x86register &operator =(const uint64_t &v){
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
      bytes[i] = (v >> (i * 8)) & 0xff;
    return *this;
  }

  x86register &operator =(const uint32_t &v){
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      bytes[i] = (v >> (i * 8)) & 0xff;
    return *this;
  }

  x86register &operator =(const uint16_t &v){
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
      bytes[i] = (v >> (i * 8)) & 0xff;
    return *this;
  }

  x86register &operator =(const uint8_t &v){
    bytes[0] = v;
    return *this;
  }

  operator uint64_t(){
    uint64_t res = 0;
    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
      res = (res << 8) + bytes[i];
    return res;
  }

  operator uint32_t(){
    uint32_t res = 0;
    for (int i = 4; i >= 0; i--)
      res = (res << 8) + bytes[i];
    return res;
  }

  operator uint16_t(){
    uint16_t res = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i >= 0; i--)
      res = (res << 8) + bytes[i];
    return res;
  }

  operator uint8_t(){
    return bytes[0];
  }

};
```

This simple class should work regardless of endianness on the running platform. Also, you probably want to add a few other accessors/mutators to handle the HSB (AH, BH, etc) of word registers.

Comment: Type punning a union in C++ is undefined behavior. You cannot write to one member and then read from another.

Comment: There's only one thing wrong in the code above: x86 registers have a maximum length of 4 bytes; although x86_64 do have 8, so the code is both valid for x86 and x86_64. In other words you should've called the class x86_64register. Great work! Thanks :)

Comment: thanks, I'm getting used to IA64, I assumed this was what you wanted. Well, I guess you can remove the extra code :)

Answer (score 1):

You can extract parts of eax using bitwise operations, like this:

```
void main()
{
    int eax, ax, ah, al;
    eax = 0xAB12CDEF;
    ax = eax & 0x0000FFFF;
    ah = (eax & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
    al = eax & 0x000000FF;
    printf("ax = eax & 0x0000FFFF           = 0x%X\n", ax);
    printf("ah = (eax & 0x0000FF00) >> 8    = 0x%X\n", ah);
    printf("al = eax & 0x000000FF           = 0x%X\n", al);
}
```

Output

```
ax = eax & 0x0000FFFF           = 0xCDEF
ah = (eax & 0x0000FF00) >> 8    = 0xCD
al = eax & 0x000000FF           = 0xEF
```

You could also define macro like that:

```
#define AX(dw) ((dw) & 0x0000FFFF)
#define AH(dw) ((dw) & 0x0000FF00) >> 8)
#define AL(dw) ((dw) & 0x000000FF)

void main()
{
    int eax = 0xAB12CDEF;
    cout << "ax = " << hex << AX(eax) << endl; // prints ax = 0xCDEF
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to work as simply as you've put the example ints, you can get away with it through reinterpret casts, though this violates pointer aliasing rules, so the behavior is undefined.

```
std::uint32_t eax = 0xAB12CDEF;
std::uint16_t& ax = reinterpret_cast<std::uint16_t*>(&eax)[1];
std::uint8_t& ah = reinterpret_cast<std::uint8_t&>(ax);
std::uint8_t& al = (&ah)[1];
```

The second line casts the address of eax to a `std::uint16_t*`, by applying `[1]` to that, you get the second half of the 32 bits.

The third line is just a cast to `uint8_t`, which works because ah will be the same as the front of ax.

Indexing into the address of `ah` by 1 gives the following byte, which is `al`.

What you're trying to do seems pretty unsafe and strange though.  So to get the most similar behavior in the sanest way, you could just use a custom type.  **However** the results will be consistent from machine to machine in the below, but they won't in the above because of different endian schemes.

```
class Reg {
    private:
        std::uint32_t data_;
    public:
        Reg(std::uint32_t in) : data_{in} { }

        std::uint32_t ex() const {
           return data_;
        }

        std::uint16_t x() const {
            return static_cast<std::uint16_t>(data_ & 0xFFFF);
        }

        std::uint8_t h() const {
            return static_cast<std::uint8_t>((data_ & 0xFF00) >> 8);
        }

        std::uint8_t l() const {
            return static_cast<std::uint8_t>(data_ & 0xFF);
        }
};
```